# Bind jQuery function to display of image (via Stellar.js)

Tags: jquery, css, function, jquery-plugins, bind

I am attempting to use Bootstrap (responsive) and Stellar.js to create a nice parallax layout. The issue I'm having is that (as per the Stellar.js documentation) **the image/div must have a defined height** to avoid the problem of the image popping in and out (as per https://github.com/markdalgleish/stellar.js/issues/7).

As I am using the responsive layout, it is necessary that the height definition is set dynamically (so that the image is not distorted when it is displayed on on smaller viewports).

Furthermore, Stellar.js sets the element as *display: none* until it appears, so it is not possible to simply check the size of the image when the page is loaded. As a result I need to find a way to **identify the height of the image once Stellar.js amends this to be *display: block* so I can bind a function to this event**

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! I can provide more information where necessary.

**Additional Details:**

Here is an example of the HTML element I am using. It is worth noting that the height reference still needs to be applied to the image even-though the Stellar plugin is functioning on it's parent div.

```
<div class="span6">
  <div  data-stellar-ratio="1.7" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-700">
    <img src="img/portfolio/web/hero.png" alt="Website design and development service">
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is an update to the Stellar.js plugin I have attempted to make in relation to the suggestions:

```
hideElement: function($elem) {

    var sImg = $elem.children('img'),
        imgHeight = sImg.height();

    sImg.css({ height: imgHeight });
    $elem.hide();
}
```

Alas this still results in the image having "height: 0px" applied, which would suggest the calculation is happening prior to the image being loaded or after it is hidden! I cannot understand why this is.

Comment: I haven't used this plugin before, but maybe you can use this line `hideElement: function($elem) { $elem.hide(); }` and add, let's say style, to it `hideElement: function($elem) { $elem.css({ height: $elem.height() }).hide(); }` before the element is hidden

Comment: Sounds plausible! I'll jump on it when I get back tonight & will report with the results. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Morpheus Thank you for your suggestion. In theory I believe this should work, however in practice it does not. I've updated the post with details of the coding I have used. If you have any other suggestions I'd be very grateful!

Comment: Open jquery.stellar.js and comment this line `particle.isHidden = true;`, see what happens. If image still not visible, then it means problem lays outside plugin. Post back your findings :)

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow what removing that line does... However, I tried it & now the element doesn't display at all! To clarify, previously, the element was visible. When scrolling down the page, Stellar worked (in that the element's position was animated), however when it reaches the top of the viewport, it suddenly disappears. After commenting out the line as suggested, it now doesn't load at at all. If you can suggest anything else I'd really appreciate it. Thank you for all your help so far @Morpheus & merry Christmas!